# SphinxSearch: is it possible to build word frequencies from realtime indexes?

Tags: indexing, sphinx, word-frequency

I know it is possible to build a list of stopwords with frequencies from indexes generated from a *source* using *rotate*.

Can this be done with realtime indexes as well? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`indextool`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-indextool) now has --dumpdict. Which with a dict=keywords index (which probably is because using RT), will dump the word frequences.

Comment: Just a remark: this feature was added in 2.1.1-beta version. Thanks!